# SetModel() for Multi Filter Api

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using ag-grid-enterprise, i need to use this `setModel()` for a API Call.

Assume this is the case,
(Note: this is for SimpleFilter, whereas i'm searching for MultiFilter)

`countryFilterComponent.setModel({ values: countriesEndingWithStan });`

What i'm trying to achieve?

i need to make an API call to the grid so that i can filter a column with these values ['Open','Closed','Pending']

This is the Multi filter i'm talking about...
[image]

I tried like this

```
    stateFilterComponent.setModel({
    filterModels:[null,
      { filterValues: ['Ready','Analysis','Fix'] }]
    });
```